# Vectors Notation Meaning

Tags: vectors

I have a question that asks for vectors a b and c, to calculate:

$\alpha a + \beta b + \gamma c$

I have no idea what this notation means: $\alpha$

If someone could clarify, that'd be awesome

Comment: $\alpha$ appears to be an arbitrary scalar, as do $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: most likely, $\alpha, \beta,$ and $\gamma$ are scalars and thus you're looking at a linear combination of vectors $a,b,$ and $c$ whose scalars are over a particular field, $\mathbb{F}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are scalars while $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the vectors. You need to perform three scalar multiplications then add the resultant vectors. That is what the question is asking you to do.

Comment: What if I'm not given values for the scalars? Do I leave them as variables? I'm only given values for the vectors.